# Binding Variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, data-binding

**Problem:**

Exception Details: System.Data.EntitySqlException: The query syntax is not valid. Near term '<', line 8, column 16.

**Code Behind:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int Id = 3;

        Page.DataBind();
    }
```

**project.aspx.cs**

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ProjectEntityDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=DBEntities" DefaultContainerName="DBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="projects" Select="it.[Id], it.[ClientId], it.[Name], it.[Description]"
    Where="it.ClientId = <%# Id %> " >
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

**What i have tried:**
[ASP.NET databinding / getting variables from codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271854/asp-net-databinding-getting-variables-from-codebehind)

I know it's too easy but i'm not able to figure out where the problem really is why i'm not able to bind the code behind data.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of the following example
In your case

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ProjectEntityDataSource.WhereParameters["Username"].DefaultValue ="3";
     Page.DataBind();
}
```

aspx

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ProjectEntityDataSource" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="name=DBEntities" DefaultContainerName="DBEntities" 
     EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="projects" Select="it.[Id], it.[ClientId], 
     it.[Name], it.[Description]" Where="it.ClientId = @Username">
      <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ProjectEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=DBEntities" DefaultContainerName="DBEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True"      
     EntitySetName="projects" Where="it.ClientId= @Id"  >
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="Id" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 1):

change like this.....it will work i think...

```
 Where='<%#"it.ClientId =" + Id.ToString %> '
```